# Is there a way to save tickets in the wallet in a ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, wallet

I'm developing an ionic app. In the app the users can buy tickets and they can enter to the pub showing this ticket.

I want to save this ticket in a wallet app. At the moment I can save a screenshot with a button, but I want to do it the more useful possible.

So, is there a way to save this tickets in the wallet, a plugin or something like this? I was searching in google a lot, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks a million.

Comment: The PassKit class is very simple, it would only take a few lines of Swift to write a basic plugin.  Your rea challenge will be compiling and signing a pass bundle and managing the push updates.

Comment: @PassKit The problem is that I don't know about ios, and I need that this work in android and iPhone devices

Comment: @Ary I have the same question and I have not found anything yet. Did you find any solution for your case?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Nothing... Sorry

Comment: I want to know if this is possible... someone got a solution?

Comment: I'll follow up with @lucas-henrique and the topick starter. Do you have any solution now?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic does not seem to have a current Wallet pluging for adding other than credit cards.